# TFS query condition on parent item OR child item

Tags: tfs

How do I create a TFS query returning all Product Backlog Items that have State=Accepted OR have child items with State=Accepted?

In below example, "Commandline Util" should be included in the query result event when the State is "New" because it have a child with state "Accepted".
[Click for query example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIc8E.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try below "Tree of workitems" query (Just replace Done with **Accepted** in your scenario ):

Note that select **Match linked work items first** under Filter options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in something like this ...
On your query your have to choose "Tree of workitems".
Adjust the fields you want to use to adapt my example where I'm using State to your Blocked field.

You can add/remove filters as needed.
Query result will bring all top level workitems matching your filters plus related children that match the children's filters.

Change the last filter options where it says match top-level workitems first to Match linked work items first.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I'm afraid it does not give the result I'm looking for. I've added an example to my question so I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Based on your new info I believe that you can change the "Match top-level work items first" to Match linked work items first. That should do it.

Comment: I already did. But I get this message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but not change the publicly displayed post score."